# Bootstrap Selectpicker - Hide select box and always show drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a `select` element and I need this always open (dropdown) without the select box.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select name="subjectFilter[]" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" id="subjectFilter">
  <option value="1">Anatomy</option>
  <option value="2">Anesthesia</option>
  <option value="3">Biochemistry</option>
  <option value="4">Community Medicine</option>
  <option value="5">Dermatology</option>
  <option value="6">ENT</option>
  <option value="7">Forensic Medicine</option>
  <option value="8">Gynecology</option>
  <option value="9">Medicine</option>
  <option value="10">Microbiology</option>
  <option value="1431">NCERT Class X Mathematics</option>
  <option value="11">Obstetrics</option>
  <option value="13">Ophthalmology</option>
  <option value="14">Orthopedics</option>
  <option value="15">Pathology</option>
  <option value="16">Pediatrics</option>
  <option value="17">Pharmacology</option>
  <option value="18">Physiology</option>
  <option value="19">Psychiatry</option>
  <option value="1409">Radiology</option>
  <option value="21">Radiotherapy</option>
  <option value="23">Surgery</option>
  <option value="1408">Anaesthesia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Check my answer. Is there any better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got like this. But still, it shows some kind of bugs.
Does any one have better answer?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle');

 $(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select, shown.bs.select", function () {
  console.log('chnage');
  $('.btn').css('display', 'none')
 });


 $(".selectpicker").on("hidden.bs.select", function () {
  console.log('sadf');
  var name = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#" + name).selectpicker("toggle");
  $('.btn').css('display', 'none')

 });
});
```

```css
button.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-default.bs-placeholder{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select name="subjectFilter[]" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" id="subjectFilter">
  <option value="1">Anatomy</option>
  <option value="2">Anesthesia</option>
  <option value="3">Biochemistry</option>
  <option value="4">Community Medicine</option>
  <option value="5">Dermatology</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think You should try Select2 as this is the best plugin for `ComboBox` Here is a Fiddle previded by Alejandro Hope it Helps [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alelase/j79g9u6z/)

Comment: it's not for a new application. On existing application, it's implemented with `bootstrap selectpicker`

Answer (score 0):

You mean the attribute size?
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a bit tricky considering `toggle` method doesn't work right away and `refresh` needs to be used to bind the data, check out the following:

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('toggle');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select name="subjectFilter[]" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple" id="subjectFilter">
  <option value="1">Anatomy</option>
  <option value="2">Anesthesia</option>
  <option value="3">Biochemistry</option>
  <option value="4">Community Medicine</option>
  <option value="5">Dermatology</option>
  <option value="6">ENT</option>
  <option value="7">Forensic Medicine</option>
  <option value="8">Gynecology</option>
  <option value="9">Medicine</option>
  <option value="10">Microbiology</option>
  <option value="1431">NCERT Class X Mathematics</option>
  <option value="11">Obstetrics</option>
  <option value="13">Ophthalmology</option>
  <option value="14">Orthopedics</option>
  <option value="15">Pathology</option>
  <option value="16">Pediatrics</option>
  <option value="17">Pharmacology</option>
  <option value="18">Physiology</option>
  <option value="19">Psychiatry</option>
  <option value="1409">Radiology</option>
  <option value="21">Radiotherapy</option>
  <option value="23">Surgery</option>
  <option value="1408">Anaesthesia</option>
</select>
```